# Cannot install laravel bundle

Tags: php, wamp, laravel

If I type:

```
PS C:\wamp\www\laravel-master> php artisan bundle:install bootstrapper
```

I am getting:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://github.com/patricktalmadge/bootstrapper/zipball
/master): failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" -
did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\wamp\www\laravel-m
aster\laravel\cli\tasks\bundle\providers\provider.php on line 69
```

I am running WAMP Server and I have enabled `php_openssl` in `php.ini` and `ssl_module` in `httpd.conf`. I reckon that it is caused by localhost configuration issues and it is not the Laravel specific problem. What more can I check to get this working?

Comment: Did you restart the webserver?

Comment: Good. Sorry for the dumb question in that case ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The output of phpinfo() in Wamp is not the same config that PHP running from commandline is using.

To find the .ini file that PHP in CMD is running type `php --ini`.

Be sure to enable the `extension=php_openssl.dll` in that file. (just remove the semicolon in front).

Comment: that did it for me. I was hoping that WAMP would make them the same.

Answer (score 8):

This happend to me too. You need enable the extension in two php.ini files in:

1. C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.ini
2. C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini

Comment: This did it for me when no other solutions did. I hadn't realized there were two php.ini files.

Answer (score 7):

You need to make sure that the `openssl` PHP extension is enabled.

Open your `php.ini` and search for `php_openssl`. You should have something like this.

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Remove the `;` from the start and then restart Apache. You should now be able to install bundles.

---

Oops, sorry, just noticed that you did enable `openssl` and restart the server. As far as I know that should fix this problem. Sorry I can't help any further.

Answer (score -1):

I had that problem, Are you sure about the permissions of the "bundles" folder, my solution was change the permissions.